# Excel VBA simple select a part of sheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I Have 2 sheet with name like
160913-01 and 160913-01-2 and I want to select the "160913-01" part only

How to do this? My coding to get the sheet name :

```
Sheet = ActiveSheet.Name
```

Comment: You mean you want to select the sheet?

Comment: I want to use the part of sheet name for my macro: **filename = path & Sheet & "\*.txt"**

Comment: Is it a static number of characters?  If so, `left(activesheet.name,9)` will do it.

Comment: Okay thanks Joe :) add to answer so I can vote

Answer (score 0):

As long as dashes are used as the delimiters you could use the following code:

Sub GetPartSheetName()
   sName = ActiveSheet.Name
   iNumberOfDashes = CountCharacter(sName, "-")
   If iNumberOfDashes > 1 Then
      saParts = Split(sName, "-")
      sName = saParts(0) + "-" + saParts(1)
   End If
   MsgBox sName
End Sub

Function CountCharacter(ByVal value, ByVal ch)
   cnt = 0
   For i = 1 To Len(value)
      If Mid(value, i, 1) = ch Then cnt = cnt + 1
   Next
   CountCharacter = cnt
End Function